# How best to append NetworkX Degree Value to original pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using NetworkX package for some network analysis, and I'm stuck on how best to append the degree of each node back to the original dataframe.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Focal_Coach | sibling_coach_id | years_under_focal | coach_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | Bill Belichick |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | Bill Belichick |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | Andy Reid |

.etc

I'm using the Network package to create the chart, and I have this code:

```
G_weighted = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
sibling_df_agg.rename(
    columns={"Focal Coach": "source", "sibling_coach_id": "target", "years_under_focal": "weight","coach_name":"edge_attr"}
)
```

)

```
#Relabel nodes from ID to name    
G_weighted = nx.relabel_nodes(G_weighted,coach_dict)
```

When I try to run the Degree function to append a column, it returns a tuple of the Coach Name and Degree.

```
sibling_df_agg['Degree']=G_weighted.degree(sibling_df_agg['coach_name'])
```

The new dataframe would look like this:

| Focal_Coach | sibling_coach_id | years_under_focal | coach_name | Degree`enter code here` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | Bill Belichick | (Bill Belichick ,2) |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | Bill Belichick | (Bill Belichick ,2) |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | Andy Reid | (Andy Reid, 1) |

I've tried adding a [1] to the code to return the number, but that just copied the Degree for the coach in the [1] dataframe row.

```
sibling_df_agg['Degree']=G_weighted.degree(sibling_df_agg['coach_name'][1]) #did not work
```

I'm wanting it to just return a number so that I can do some math manipulation to the data frame (e.g. return only coaches who have a degree greater than X).  How best can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to unpack the tuple first and turn it into a series.
Changed the line to

```
  sibling_names,sibling_degrees = zip(*G_weighted.degree(sibling_df_agg['coach_name']))
  sibling_df_agg['degree_cnt'] = pd.Series(sibling_degrees)
```

and it worked perfectly.